# How to label encode a DataFrame column which contains both numbers and strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have this DataFrame column

```
+-------------------------------------+--+
|                df:                  |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
| Index           Ticket*             |  |
| 0               254326              |  |
| 1               CA345               |  |
| 3               SA12                |  |
| 4               267891              |  |
| '               '                   |  |
| '               '                   |  |
| '               '                   |  |
| 700            CA356                |  |
+-------------------------------------+--+
```

It contains two kinds of values. Some are pure numbers and others are strings having letters and numbers.

Many rows have the same letters (CA345, CA675 etc). I would like to group and label the rows with same letters with the same numbers.

Eg. All rows having "CA" labelled as 0, all rows having "SA" labelled as 1.

Remaining rows all have six digit numbers (no letters in them). I would like to label all such rows with the same number (say 2 for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Approach**

Define a custom function, check if the row `isinstance(val, str)` and contains `"SA"` or `"CA"`

```py
def label_ticket(row):
    if isinstance(row['Ticket'], str) and 'CA' in row['Ticket']:
        return 0
    if isinstance(row['Ticket'], str) and 'SA' in row['Ticket']:
        return 1
    return 2
```

Apply the custom function to new column `df('Label')`.

```
df['Label'] = df.apply(label_ticket, axis=1)
print(df)
     Ticket  Label
0    254326      2
1     CA345      0
2      SA12      1
3    267891      2
700   CA356      0
```

---

**2nd Approach**

Further understanding the situation, it seems you have no idea what instances will come up in `df['Ticket']`. In this case you can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to search all string pattern and classify them into category accordingly.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ticket'],
                  data=[[254326],
                        ['CA345'],
                        ['SA12'],
                        [267891],
                        ['CA356']])
df['Pattern'] = df['Ticket'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.split("[^a-zA-Z]*", str(x))))
df_label = pd.DataFrame(df['Pattern'].unique(), columns=['Pattern']).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'index': 'Label'})
df = df.merge(df_label, how='left')
print(df)

   Ticket Pattern  Label
0  254326              0
1   CA345      CA      1
2    SA12      SA      2
3  267891              0
4   CA356      CA      1
```

Comment: But the first thing that I need to do is to figure out a way to find out what all such instances are present in the series.

Comment: @NitinSingh i have updated the answer with another approach to do classification based on string pattern appeared in `df["Ticket"]`, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough knowledge of python but

you may have try [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract)

and 
`regular expression`

Like:

```
ptrn=r'(?P<CA>(CA[\d]+))|(?P<SA>(SA[\d]+))|(?P<DIGIT>[\d]{6})'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ls={'tk':[ '254326' ,  'CA345',  'SA12'    ,  '267891'  ,        'CA356' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
s=df['tk'].str.extract(ptrn,expand=False)
newDf={0:[x for x in s['CA'] if pd.isnull(x)==False],1:[x for x in s['SA'] if pd.isnull(x)==False],2:[x for x in s['DIGIT'] if pd.isnull(x)==False]}
print(newDf)
```

out put:

```
{0: ['CA345', 'CA356'], 1: ['SA12'], 2: ['254326', '267891']}
```

[demo](https://repl.it/@FrustetedD/RowdyTragicReference)